# cocoa open multiple files with associated app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file

I have an array of filenames that i would like to pass to an external application for opening. I'd like to do one of the following:

a) Somehow instruct OSX to open all these files with an associated application, but it must invoke the target app's openFiles NSApplication delegate method
b) Specify the application to open these files with (and also invoke openFiles)

Basically it doesn't matter which solution to realise, because these files will be associated with the target application anyway. How would i do one of these things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open a whole bunch of files at once, send the shared NSWorkspace object [an `openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:), or call [the `LSOpenURLsWithRole` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSOpenURLsWithRole) or [the `LSOpenFromURLSpec` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSOpenFromURLSpec). Either way, you'll pass an array of URLs to items to open.

Each one of these will let you identify a specific application to use. NSWorkspace lets you specify it by bundle identifier, while the two Launch Services functions let you provide the URL or `FSRef` to a specific application bundle.

> … it must invoke the target app's openFiles NSApplication delegate method

That isn't possible to require, because (a) the application may be document-based, in which case it probably does not have an NSApplication delegate and, even if it does, such a delegate would probably not respond to `application:openFiles:`, and (b) the application may not be Cocoa-based, in which case it would handle the Open Documents Apple Event directly. None of this is your application's business, so don't worry about it.

Comment: It is possible to require in this case, because i'm creating that application and i am implementing the openFiles: method. So it would be great if i could retrieve all filenames at once in the target application.

Comment: Marius: Fair enough. As long as you open all the documents at once, not separately, you should get a single `applictaion:openFiles:` message on the receiving end. Also, you may want to read the source code for the Growl framework, because we do something similar, opening a document with GrowlHelperApp. In particular, you'll probably want to use the same opening flags we do.

Comment: Thank you. Will try your suggestions.

Comment: It seems i got happy too early. I've tried openURLs: method. It seems to work and activates the target app, but the files aren't passed to application:openFiles: method. So how do i receive them then? I don't know of any other methods.

Comment: Never mind. I'll just use distributed notifications to pass the list of files in addition to supporting openFile: and openFiles: methods.

Comment: How did you create the URLs? Maybe you didn't pass valid file: URLs. If you used one of the LSOpen functions, did it return an error?

Answer (score 0):

First add your video files to Resources Folder.The code like follow:

```
NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString* videoPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Contents/Resources/video.mov"];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:videoPath];
```